# How to use different type of pointer with the same name?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a problem with reducing the number of `for`-loops. They do the same thing for different type.

Should I use void pointers or something else.

Is it possible to reduce the number of code?

```
  void smt(int nb, int iform, void *ptr)//example function
  {
      int *ipt;// pointers definitions
      float *fpt;
      double *dpt;
      if( iform == 1 )
      {
          ipt = (int *) ptr;
          for( int i = 0; i < nb; i++ )
              ipt[i]=i;
      }
      else if( iform == 2)
      {
          fpt  = (float *)ptr;
          for( int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
              fpt[i] = 2.71;
      }
      else
      {
          dpt = (double *)ptr;
          for( int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
              dpt[i] = i*3.14159;
      }
   } 
   int main(void)
   {
       int nb = 5;
       float iform = 2;
       float *a = malloc(nb*sizeof(float)); //allocate memory 
       float *fpt;
       //there should be double *dpt and so on  
       smt(nb, iform, a );
       if( iform == 1)
       {
           for( int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
               printf("a = %d\n", a[i]);
       }
       else if( iform  == 2)
       {
           for( int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
               printf("a = %f\n", a[i]);
       }
       else
       {
           for( int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
               printf("a = %f\n", a[i]);
       }            
            return 0;
   }
```

Comment: You cannot do this kind of cast. Especially int to double as their size is different. Your allocated ptr can overflow.

Comment: They are **not** doing the same thing for different types. The assignments are quite different.

Comment: Your only option is to move to C++ and use templates.

Comment: Why do you wanna reduce your code? There is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you allocate memory with

```
float *a = malloc(nb*sizeof(float));
```

you can use the pointer `a` as an array of float. The compiler knows how big a `float` is for the calculation of the address of the array element `a[i]`.

If you cast the pointer to a different type, the size of an array element may be different resulting in a different address. With `i != 0` you will store your data at different addresses when you use `a[i]` or `((double*)a)[i]`.

To store different types in an array I suggest to use a `union`. Instead of magic numbers for `iform` I suggest to use an enum type (or `#define`s). To reduce the number of for loops you can move the comparison of `iform` into the loop body.

```
union data {
    int intVal;
    float floatVal;
    double doubleVal;
};

enum dataType {
    INT_DATA = 1,
    FLOAT_DATA = 2,
    DOUBLE_DATA = 3
}

void smt(int nb, enum dataType iform, union data *ptr)//example function
{
    for( int i = 0; i < nb; i++ )
    {
        switch( iform )
        {
        case INT_DATA:
            ptr[i].intVal = i;
            break
        case FLOAT_DATA:
            ptr[i].floatVal = 2.71;
            break;
        case DOUBLE_DATA:
        default:
            ptr[i].doubleVal = i*3.14159;
            break;
        }
    }
} 

int main(void)
{
    int nb = 5;
    enum dataType iform = FLOAT_DATA;
    union data *a = malloc(nb*sizeof(union data )); //allocate memory 

    smt(nb, iform, a );
    for( int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
    {
        switch( iform )
        {
        case INT_DATA:
            printf("a = %d\n", a[i].intVal);
            break
        case FLOAT_DATA:
            printf("a = %f\n", (double)a[i].floatVal);
            break;
        case DOUBLE_DATA:
        default:
            printf("a = %f\n", a[i].doubleVal);
            break;
        }
   }            
   return 0;
}
```

It would be possible to use a void pointer and to casts but you would have to use the pointer for the biggest data type and instead of casting the pointer to the start of the array `a` yopu would have to cast the address of the array element. Assuming `double` is the biggest data type you could do something like this.

```
double *a = malloc(nb*sizeof(*a)); //allocate memory 

int *ipt = (int*)&(a[i]);
*ipt = i;
```

but I don't recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

As C does not know templates one could fall back to use the preprocessor and some (in?)sane macros:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> /* for M_PI */

#ifndef M_PI
#  define M_PI (3.14159265359)
#endif 

#define SMT_INIT(T, p, nb) do { \
  (p) = malloc(nb * sizeof (T)); \
} while (0)

#define SMT(T, p, nb, stmt) do { \
  for (size_t i = 0; i < (nb); ++i) \
  { \
    ((T*)(p))[i] = (T)(stmt); \
  } \
} while (0)

#define SMT_PRINT(T, p, nb, fmt) do { \
  for (size_t i = 0; i < (nb); ++i) \
  { \
    printf("%" fmt "\n", ((T*)(p))[i]); \
  } \
} while (0)

int main(void)
{
  void * p = NULL;
  int iform = ...;
  size_t nb = ...;

  int result = 0;

  switch (iform)
  {
    case 1:
      SMT_INIT(int, p, nb);
      SMT(int, p, nb, i);
      SMT_PRINT(int, p, nb, "d");

      break;

    case 2:
      SMT_INIT(float, p, nb);
      SMT(float, p, nb, 2.71);
      SMT_PRINT(float, p, nb, "f");

      break;

    case 3:
      SMT_INIT(double, p, nb);
      SMT(double, p, nb, i * M_PI);
      SMT_PRINT(double, p, nb, "f");

      break;

    case 4:
      result = -1;
      break;
  }

  free(p);

  return 0 == result ?EXIT_SUCCESS :EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Introducing another macro wrapping the other three stuff can be obfuscated even more:

```
#define SMT_ALL(T, p, nb, stmt, fmt) do { \
  SMT_INIT(T, p, nb); \
  SMT(T, p, nb, stmt); \
  SMT_PRINT(T, p, nb, fmt); \
} while (0)

int main(void)
{
  ...

  switch (iform)
  {
    case 1:
      SMT_ALL(int, p, nb, i, "d");

      break;

    case 2:
      SMT_ALL(float, p, nb, 2.71, "f");

      break;

    case 3:
      SMT_ALL(double, p, nb,  i * M_PI, "f");

      break;

    case 4:
      result = -1;
      break;
  }

  ...

}
```